# PHP Function call with parameters/variables

Tags: php, function

I have two functions in one Controller class and I want to call a getFunction with five variables. Here is the function call

```
public function editItem()
{
    $reqNote = 1;
    $reqTore = 2;
    $reqTorvorlage = 3;
    $reqGelbRot = 1;
    $reqRot = 0;
    $vPunkte = $this->getPoints($reqNote, $reqTore, $reqTorvorlage, $reqGelbRot, $reqRot);
}
```

And here is the function which should calculate a new value return.

```
public function getPoints()
{
    $vNote = $reqNote;
    $vTore = $reqTore;
    $vTorvorlage = $reqTorvorlage;
    $vRot = $reqRot;
    $vGelbRot = $reqGelbRot;
    $vPosition = 1;

    $vPunkteResult = $vToreP + $vTorvorlageP + $vRotP + $vGelbRotP + $vNoteP;

    return $vPunkteResult;
}
```

What I am doing wrong with my function call because at the moment I get `$reqNote` is not found?

Comment: Maybe declare your arguments in the function .. `public function getPoints($reqNote, ....)`

Comment: Really, read up on http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php and http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your function currently looks as though the intention was to add the arguments (it is actually returning the sum of undefined variables i.e. $vToreP is never assigned, nor are the function arguments), you could take a short-cut:

```
<?php
function sumThings()
{
    return array_sum(func_get_args());
}

var_dump(sumThings(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6));
```

Output:

```
21
```

Answer (score 2):

simply add  the variable in signature

```
public function getPoints($reqNote, $reqTore, $reqTorvorlage, $reqGelbRot, $reqRot)
{
    $vNote = $reqNote;
    $vTore = $reqTore;
    $vTorvorlage = $reqTorvorlage;
    $vRot = $reqRot;
    $vGelbRot = $reqGelbRot;
    $vPosition = 1;

    $vPunkteResult = $vToreP + $vTorvorlageP + $vRotP + $vGelbRotP + $vNoteP;

    return $vPunkteResult;
}
```

Comment: (Of course this is a pretty useless function in its current form that will always return 0.)

Answer (score 0):

Update the function signature. It should know that it is expecting 5 variables.

```
 public function  getPoints($reqNote, $reqTore, $reqTorvorlage, $reqGelbRot, $reqRot)
{
                $vNote = $reqNote;
                $vTore = $reqTore;
                $vTorvorlage = $reqTorvorlage;
                $vRot = $reqRot;
                $vGelbRot = $reqGelbRot;
                $vPosition = 1;

                $vPunkteResult = $vToreP + $vTorvorlageP + $vRotP + $vGelbRotP + $vNoteP;
                return $vPunkteResult;
        }
```